# Tibco BW Conditional Flow

Tags: rest, tibco, tibco-business-works

I need to invoke a REST service in a Tibco BW, however, the endpoint depends on some condition.

my question is how we can implement a conditional flow in the Tibco BW.

Answer (score 1):

One approach commonly used is to encapsulate the call to the REST back end in a sub process and at runtime use dynamic sub process call feature to call the relevant subprocess.

You can also try to tweak the ressource path in some scenario.